# Is "trained up" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, phrasal-verbs

When I hear expressions like "you need to get trained up", I think the *up* is, at best, superfluous and probably grammatically incorrect.

Is that the case, or does the *up* serve a purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Up* has numerous uses and, as the OED notes, ‘the variety . . . is so great that the adverb comes to present a number of highly divergent and even directly opposite senses’.

Your example is certainly grammatical. The OED’s definition in this sense is

> To cultivate or develop (the mind, the spirit, a faculty, etc.),
>   especially for a specified purpose; to accustom to performing a
>   specified function. Also with *up*.

The use of *train up* isn’t new. The entry gives this supporting citation from the mid-seventeenth century:

> How much more ought a Christian to train up his own heart, and
>   accustome it this way, to be his continual remembrancer of himself.

Comment: And there is always the biblical Proverbs 22:6: "*Train up* a child in the way he should go: and when he is old, he will not depart from it."

Comment: @JLG: correct, in the [KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2022:6&version=KJV). Not the case in more modern translations like the [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2022:6&version=NIV1984).